# Using mocha and chai with import synax in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, pact

I'm trying to add [Pact](https://docs.pact.io/) tests to my existing VueJS application but I'm having trouble even with the most basic test setup (using mocha with chai).

This is the basic test to see if things are working at all:

```
import { should } from "chai";

describe("setup", () => {
  it("should work", () => {
    var x = true;
    x.should.be.equal(true);
  });
});
```

Running this with the following command:

```
mocha --require @babel/preset-env test/pact/**/*.pact.js
```

This results in:

```
import { should } from "chai";
       ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

From what I understood I need to transpile. After searching for similar issues I added this:

**babel.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@vue/app", "@babel/preset-env"]
};
```

Same effect.

It works when using e.g.

```
var should = require("chai").should();

describe("setup", () => {
  it("should work", () => {
    var x = true;
    x.should.be.equal(true);
  });
});
```